# How can I constrain generic parameter to be assignable to string?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function with a generic parameter `T`. I intend this generic parameter to be either a sum types of different constant strings, like `"alpha"|"beta"`, or an enum with string values, like `enum ExampleEnum { Alpha = "ALPHA", Beta = "BETA" }`. Either way, in runtime all the values will be strings and I should be able to use them wherever strings are used.

Here's the example function:

```
function chooseRandom<T>(inputs: T[], callback: (chosen: T) => void) {
  const t = inputs[4]; // die roll, guaranteed to be random
  acceptsOnlyString(t);
  callback(t);
}

function acceptsOnlyString(input: string) {
  console.log(input);
}
```

And of course, with this, I get an error when I call `acceptsOnlyString`:

> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'

I included the callback function in this example to explain why I can't just use `string` — the users of `chooseRandom` function will want to specify a callback that only accepts `T` and not any possible string.

How do I explain to typescript that `T` should be constrained to types that are assignable to a string?

Comment: BTW, your `inputs: T[]` should be typed as `inputs: readonly T[]` - that will avoid covariance issues. My personal rule-of-thumb is to _always_ use `readonly T[]` array types because not only for support for array variance, but also because it helps prevent accidental or unintentional parameter mutation.

Comment: `inputs[4]; // die roll, guaranteed to be random` <-- do I spy an [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/221/) reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict what types are allowed for a generic with the `extends` keyword:

```
function chooseRandom<T extends string>(inputs: T[], callback: (chosen: T) => void) {
  const t = inputs[4]; // die roll, guaranteed to be random
  acceptsOnlyString(t);
  callback(t);
}
```

With this restriction, typescript knows it's safe to pass `t` into `acceptsOnlyString`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFnOBnApgJQIZgAmcAtgDwAqiWAHlFkRohlAE4xgDmAfABQcAHEFAwAuRBQDaAXQA0yPABtFAIzwQA1uN6pMDcRQCUiALzdEANzgxCxgN4AoRMgQtEUU4kHCMkgCzSANyIAPQhiIQwWIiscMrynCB4rAT0WITucIgq0SlEpE6I6hBYAiIA8mCKAJ4AymwcnLxQhoGFEEqq6hrNrQ4Avg4OoJCwCEUQJWUYlTX17Fz8YEJQ4iwLnPbtrnFYAHSKcE3eLW2DDgwgJBJYbo7OzsDongDkT3AvsoXOaqymL79PgMhhBXB51o0AIKsFLVTySABEKCwyjgCPkCIA7nBWIpCAigg5QWA3BgBFgIDBgDAIPMoTC8NVtEiUYcEYgAD6ILE4vEIwwyeEs1Ho7nY3H4wnEtyXEjQ2Hwii3KB7d7yJUsPa-QkOMKIADi6AyIGwYiJaD0+HyJF4EK48sZ8l4rFuIEUq2YDS4xjMiDs-UM5vQ2CtxBtZIpVJpdPtDOqTpdGDdHuFbM5Yt5+J95n9gd0loIYd4sod8cQztd7oMyuzfoDQz1ACE8MbTeIgwXrbxJABGeQAJjk5cTyfEYCuOVYtdzHZDhdItq9nFLCcrHo1LVMOYDQA)

Comment: Well now I feel like an idiot because despite 10+ years of C# experience I never would have thought that type `"constant"` extends `string`, but that's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Think of typescript's `extends` as meaning "is a subset of". So `string` is the set of all strings, and `"constant"` is the set with just the specific string "constant". This set is a subset of the full set.

Comment: @MaxYankov I'm not sure what the utility is of making `chooseRandom` a generic function if your code is always going to treat `T` as a `string` anyway - I know it matters for your `callback` param but is it necessary? I've seen lots of TS code that tries to shoe-horn-in generics when far-simpler non-generic code works just as fine - just something to consider.

Comment: I've written a toy example because I don't want to complicate the question and break my NDA, but yes, it keeps the `callback` function type-safe, which is important to me.